# echo out div 1 if user favourites is 13 or less else echo out div 2?

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to find a way of displaying a div which says "add this user to your favourites" but i only want this to display if a user has less than 13 favourites. so as soon as they have 13 favourites div1 will hide and div 2 will show.

i am currently echoing out my div on a different page to where the user favourites are echoed :

```
<?php
$account_type = account_type();
while ($acctype = mysql_fetch_array($account_type)) 

if ($profile_id == $_SESSION['user_id'])  { 
}else{
 if ($acctype['account_type'] == 'User')  {

    echo "<div class=\"infobox-profile\"><strong>Add to Favourites ".$profile[2]."</strong> - to add or remove this user to your favourites <a href=\"add_favorutie.php?to=".$profile_id."\">click here</a>";
echo "<div class=\"infobox-fav-close\"></div></div>";
 }}
 ?>
```

then on another page i echo out the users favourites:

```
<?php
$favourites_set = get_favourites();
$fav_count = mysql_num_rows($favourites_set);
while ($fav = mysql_fetch_array($favourites_set)) {

    echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id={$fav['fav_id']}\"><img width=\"60px\" height=\"60px\" class=\"fav_pic\" src=\"data/photos/{$fav['duo_id']}/_default.jpg\" /></a>";

        }
```

so what i want is when the 'favourites set has echoed out 13 favourites the div that asks if the user would like to add any more favourites disapears and echoes out another div eg "user favourites exceeded"

i have tried to do the following but im new to php and really need help, please can someone show me what i need to do.

```
 <? if(mysql_num_rows($favourites_set) < 13) {
        while ($fav = mysql_fetch_array($favourites_set)) {
        $account_type = account_type();
        if ($acctype['account_type'] == 'User')  {

        if ($profile_id == $_SESSION['user_id'])  { 

        echo "favourites exceeded";


}else{

     if ($acctype['account_type'] == 'User')  {

    echo "<div class=\"infobox-profile\"><strong>add favourites ".$profile[2]."</strong> - to add or remove this user to your favourites <a href=\"add_favourites.php?to=".$profile_id."\">click here</a>";
echo "<div class=\"infobox-fav-close\"></div></div>";
 }}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @njk +1 for the linktastic (and most correct) comment

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to keep count of how many iterations your loop has completed using a count variable, and use that to test against.

Example:

```
$count=1;

while ($fav = mysql_fetch_array($favourites_set)) 
{
    if ($count<13)
    {
        //loop has not yet iterated 13 times
        //do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        //this loop has iterated 13 times or more. do other stuff.
        //echo out your 'user favourites exceeded' div 
        //and optionally, break the loop to prevent repetition.
        break;
    }
    $count++; //increment the loop counter
}
```

EDIT: I'm not going to bash you over the head with it but use `mysqli` or `PDO`, not `mysql` - see the comment on your question for details.